# Range of a quadratic equation

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-writing

Consider a question :
Find the range of 
$f(x)= \frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2} $

I found two methods for solving this

**Method 1:**
The domain of this function is $\mathbb{R} - {2}$ .So if $x$ is not equal to $2$ , $f(2)$ does  not lie in the range $f(2)=2+2=4$

THEREFORE **range=$\mathbb{R}-{4}$**

**Method 2** 
Let $\frac{x^2- 4}{x-2} = y
\iff x^2-4=xy-2y \iff x^2-(y)x-(4-2y)=0$ as $x$ is real
 ${ b^2 -4ac\ge 0}$
    $ y^2+4(4-2y)\ge 0 \iff (y-4)^2 \ge 0$

THEREFORE range is ${\mathbb{R}}$

Two different ranges

Comment: The function $f(x)$ is not a quadratic equation but rather a cubic one.

Comment: Please, use latex, it's difficult to understand. I tried to edit, but not sure if everything is right.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

In method (2) observe that you multiplied the equation $f(x)=y$ by $x-2$. So, for $x=2$ the resulting equation becomes $0=0y$ which is valid for all $y$. This shows that the second equation is not equivalent to the original equation for $x=2$. In general, multiplying an equation by a factor can increase the set of solutions, if there are values of the variables for which the factor becomes $0$, like for $x-2$.

In method (2) you would need to treat the case $y=4$ separately and search for solutions of $f(x)=4$ inside the domain $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\ x\neq2\}$. In that domain $f(x)=x+2$. This gives you the equation $x+2=4$, which has the solution $x=2$, which is not in the domain. So, $f(x)=4$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>2$ we obtain:
$$f'(x)=2x+\frac{4}{(x-2)^2}>0.$$
Also, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2^+}f(x)=-\infty$$ and since $f$ is a continuous function we obtain the range: $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

In method 2, we can not use symbol $\Leftrightarrow$ because $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=y$ is not same as $x^2-4=xy-2y$ because the later expression is true for $x=2$ but the  former is not true for $x=2$. To make it true apply the condition that $x\ne2$. Thus eventually by method 2 also we would get the correct range as $\mathbb{R}-\{4\}$